# Bootstrap how to put the nav bar in a drop menu for short screen?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I try to set up my index page from a combination of the [jumbotron](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/jumbotron/) and the [fix nav bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) bootstrap examples.

Using the fix nav bar page of bootstrap, if one reduces the width of the window instead of a navbar list, you obtain a drop menu with the content of the navbar. In my case it does not work. I do not understand what is missing there.

Nevertheless, if I copy the lines between the `<nav>` and `</nav>` html tags into the bootstrap example pages it works.

This is my index.html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head><meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Association M'Langues">

<link rel="icon" href="">

<title>Mon Association</title>

<!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.5.0 -->
<title>Mon Association</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.7.4" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Association" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta name="description" content="L’association" />
<meta property="og:description" content="L’association" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4000/index2" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:4000/index2" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Association" />
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"description":"L’association .","@type":"WebPage","url":"http://localhost:4000/index2","headline":"Association","@context":"http://schema.org"}</script>
<!-- End Jekyll SEO tag -->

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- HEADER --><!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Association </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li class="">
            <a href="/activites/">Activités</a>
        </li>
      <li class="">
            <a href="/actualites">Actualités de l&#39;association</a>
        </li>
      <li class="">
            <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
        </li>
      <li class="">
            <a href="/about/">À Propos</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Association </h1>
    <p>L'association a pour objectif la promotion .</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">

      <p>Bonjour !</p>

<p>Bienvenu sur le site de l’Association </p>


      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- FOOTER  --><footer>

    <p class="copyright">Association </p>

    <p>Published with <a href="https://pages.github.com">GitHub Pages</a></p>
</footer>
</div>




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the [Bootstrap Basic Template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template), the `JQuery` plugin should be included before the `Bootstrap minified javascript file`.

Comment: I put the `bootstrap.min.js` at the end after the footer and it works now ! Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, I made and answer with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Bootstrap** minified javascript file:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

should be included after the **JQuery** minified javascript file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, your code should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Association M'Langues">

    <link rel="icon" href="">    
    <title>Mon Association</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.5.0 -->
    <title>Mon Association</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.7.4" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Association" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta name="description" content="L’association" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="L’association" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4000/index2" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:4000/index2" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Association" />
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {"description":"L’association .","@type":"WebPage","url":"http://localhost:4000/index2","headline":"Association","@context":"http://schema.org"}</script>
    <!-- End Jekyll SEO tag -->

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- HEADER --><!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Association </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="">
              <a href="/activites/">Activités</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/actualites">Actualités de l&#39;association</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/about/">À Propos</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Association </h1>
        <p>L'association a pour objectif la promotion .</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">
      <p>Bonjour !</p>    
      <p>Bienvenu sur le site de l’Association </p>

      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- FOOTER  -->
      <footer>    
        <p class="copyright">Association </p>    
        <p>Published with <a href="https://pages.github.com">GitHub Pages</a></p>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap: Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```